# Linear Regression in SAS besides PROC REG

Tags: sas

Suppose I want to model Y on w, z and the interaction of w and z. PROC REG wants me to make a new variable, u=w*z, and then do a regression on w,z, and u

Isn't there some other proc that is less restrictive, where I could just specify w*z as variable to the regression, like I do in R?

Comment: I would look at PROC GLMSELECT, though I'm not an expert in regression.  [This part of the documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statugregression/61752/PDF/default/statugregression.pdf) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try PROC MODEL from SAS/ETS.

```
proc model data=foo;

y = int + Bw*w + Bz*z + Bwz*w*z;

fit y;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the | to delimit your variables. You can specify the depth on interaction terms by using @.
This will do all interaction terms, in this case the model would be height+ age + height*age.

```
proc glm data=sashelp.class;
model weight = height|age;
run;quit;
```

This will only do first order terms, i.e. no interaction

```
proc glm data=sashelp.class;
model weight = height|age @1;
run;quit;
```

Comment: Hmm...not sure I agree with your interpretation. Perhaps the OP can clarify?

Comment: I agree, but that's what height|age does :) 
Model created is height, age, height*age. If you didn't want that it would be height|age @1 would create model height, age.

Answer (score 0):

proc glm allows for that functionality

Here is some documentation on it: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#glm_toc.htm

Comment: I think this would be a good answer if you included at least a short example of using that proc to do the above example from the question, similar to how Dom showed using PROC MODEL in his answer.